# Parse.com+Ionic : Event Listeners for Notifications

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, ionic-framework

I have successfully implemented the Parse Push Notifications.
Now, I want to add event listeners such as `onNotificationReceived` `onNotificationClick` or so in Angular JS. The Parse API doesn't have any documentation about this.

Please share a documentation link or an API is present.

Note: I am building the App on Ionic Framework. Also, I am trying to avoid native android coding.